# Error running mysqldump via python - access denied

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, mysql

I have this simple code:

```
cmd = ["mysqldump", "-u Dmitriy", "-pMyPass", "dmitrii"]
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout = file)
```

if I try to execute it - I get an error:

`mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user ' Dmitriy'@'localhost' (using password: YES
when trying to connect.`

if I copy-paste this (`mysqldump -u Dmitriy -pMyPass dmitrii`)to command line - everything works.

Any suggestions why this could be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my machine I can fix it by removing the space between -u and the username.

```
cmd = ["mysqldump", "-uDmitriy", "-pMyPass", "dmitrii"]
```

Edit: just wanted to add some reasoning

Each of the arguments in your list is escaped. So your first command was more like:

```
mysqldump '-u Dmitriy' '-pMyPass' 'dmitrii'
```

If you try that from the command line you'll see that it fails with the same error whereas this works

```
mysqldump '-uDmitriy' '-pMyPass' 'dmitrii'
```

I guess it's to do with the argument parser that's used in mysql. The two argument form ('-u' followed by 'Dmitriy') will strip the whitespace (which makes sense). If you give it the single form ('-u Dmitriy') you're saying to it - there's a whitespace on the front of the username.

Comment: I was trying since you posted it  But it takes 10 mins till I can accept.

Comment: Ah interesting - didn't realise that.